# VBA Error 1004 when Copy Pasting Values and Formatting from one Sheet to Another

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, out-of-memory

I'm trying to copy the content and formatting of Rec1 to Rec2. However, I keep getting error 1004 and a message saying that Excel does not have enough memory to execute the task.
Please note that there are other macros in the worksheet

[image: error message]

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()


Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rec1")
Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rec2")

Target.Cells.Clear

Source.Cells.Copy

Target.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of copying the entire sheet, just copy the `UsedRange`.

```
Souce.UsedRange.Copy
```

You could also clear the target's used range:

```
Target.UsedRange.Clear
```